# C++ template specialization

Tags: c++

Hi I am implementing template specialization with C++, where I would like a function foo to do something if the input (and output) types are float and double, but would like foo to act differently for int.

I seem to be doing something wrong. Can you please provide me some pointers? Thanks a bunch!

```
template <typename typeA, typename typeB>
typeA foo(const typeB *pt) {
  // do something;
} 

template float foo<float, float>(const float *pt);
template double foo<double, double>(const double *pt);

template<>
int foo(const int *pt) {
  // do something different for int;
}
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: what are the two middles lines of code supposed to be good for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I was missing was `<int, int>`. complete code:

```
template <typename typeA, typename typeB>
typeA foo(const typeB *pt) {
  // do something;
} 

template float foo<float, float>(const float *pt);
template double foo<double, double>(const double *pt);

template<>
int foo<int, int>(const int *pt) {
  // do something different for int;
}
```